# IntelliJ IDEA Plugin Development Issue: ClassNotFoundException

Tags: intellij-plugin

I'm currently working on developing an IntelliJ IDEA plugin and have encountered some issues during runtime. I'm hoping experienced developers in the community can provide some insights. Here are the key details:

Issue Summary:
I have a action classes in my plugin, namely HelloWorldAction. When running the plugin, I'm facing a ClassNotFoundException indicating that class cannot be loaded properly. I've checked the classpath, plugin descriptor file, and plugin loading status, but the issue persists.

Key Information:
IntelliJ IDEA version: 2022.2.5
JDK version: 17.0.6
Plugin structure and classpath settings

Exception Information:

`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.plugdemo.HelloWorldAction`

```
<!-- Plugin Configuration File. Read more: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/plugin-configuration-file.html -->
<idea-plugin>
    <id>com.example.plugdemo</id>
    <name>Plugdemo</name>
    <vendor email="support@yourcompany.com" url="https://www.yourcompany.com">YourCompany</vendor>
    <description><![CDATA[
    Enter short description for your plugin here.<br>
    <em>most HTML tags may be used</em>
  ]]></description>
    <depends>com.intellij.modules.platform</depends>
    <extensions defaultExtensionNs="com.intellij"></extensions>
    <actions>
        <action id="demo.hello.world" class="com.example.plugdemo.HelloWorldAction" text="HelloWorld"
                description="the HelloWorld Action">
            <add-to-group group-id="HelpMenu" anchor="first"/>
        </action>
    </actions>
</idea-plugin>
```

```
package com.example.plugdemo;

import com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.AnAction;
import com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.AnActionEvent;
import com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.CommonDataKeys;
import com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.PlatformDataKeys;
import com.intellij.openapi.project.Project;
import com.intellij.openapi.ui.Messages;
import com.intellij.psi.PsiFile;

public class HelloWorldAction extends AnAction {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(AnActionEvent e) {
        Project project = e.getData(PlatformDataKeys.PROJECT);
        PsiFile psiFile = e.getData(CommonDataKeys.PSI_FILE);
        String classPath = psiFile.getVirtualFile().getPath();
        String title = "Hello World!";
        Messages.showMessageDialog(project, classPath, title, Messages.getInformationIcon());
    }
}
```

Tried Solutions:

Rebuilding the project.
Checking the plugin descriptor file to ensure the correct classpath.
Ensuring the plugin is loaded correctly in IDEA.
Has anyone in the community encountered a similar issue, or do you have alternative solutions? Any help is greatly appreciated!

If more information is needed, I can provide the plugin descriptor file, project structure screenshots, etc. Thank you all for your assistance!

Comment: This looks fine to me at first glance. What does your `build.gradle` look like?